# Как выбрать элемент, если нет уникальных идентификаторов?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь парсить страницу, но наткнулся на проблему, когда у нескольких элементов одинаковые идентификаторы.
Вот структура, которую я пытаюсь разобрать:

---

```
<div class="tabs_p">
 <div class="tabs_p_d">
  <div class="tabs_p_t">Name</div>
  <div class="tabs_p_d"></div>
 </div>
<div class="tabs_p_v">
    5016                        </div>
  </div>
<div class="tabs_p_d">
  <div class="tabs_p_t">ID</div>
  <div class="tabs_p_d"></div>
 </div>
<div class="tabs_p_v">
    506                        </div>
  </div>
<div class="tabs_p_d">
  <div class="tabs_p_t">LS</div>
  <div class="tabs_p_d"></div>
 </div>
<div class="tabs_p_v">
    485                        </div>
  </div>
<div class="tabs_p_d">
  <div class="tabs_p_t">Value</div>
  <div class="tabs_p_d"></div>
 </div>
<div class="tabs_p_v">
    100                        </div>
  </div>
```

---

Как видите, у элементов нет уникальных идентификаторов, по которым можно было бы делать выборку. Но мне, например, нужно выбрать значение, в блоке "value". Как я могу получить эту цифру 100?
Как работает код, который разбирает эту страницу, например, для получения заголовка:

```
function Parse($p1, $p2, $p3) {
 $num1 = strpos($p1, $p2);
 if ($num1 === false) return 0;
  $num2 = substr($p1, $num1);
  return strip_tags(substr($num2, 0, strpos($num2, $p3)));
                      }
$string = file_get_contents('$source');
$name = strip_tags(trim(Parse($string, '<h1 item="name">', '</h1>')));
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, может есть какой-то метод выборки не по идентификаторам, а по содержимому элементов?
Или, как вариант, выбирать последний элемент, т.к. нужный мне всегда находится в конце.

Comment: Смотри в `.tabs_p_t`, какой там текст. Если нужный - бери значение из `.tabs_p_v` которое после родительского дива.

Comment: @u_mulder я, если честно, не очень понимаю, как мне перейти к следующему, если совпадение не найдено. Полагаю, что мне нужно вывести значения в виде массива и уже перебирать его по соответствию

Comment: @myudasn пользуйтесь уже готовыми средствами которые в разы упрощают и ускоряют решение задачи. От себя, посоветовал бы [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domxpath.php) + [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php)